# Is this function differentiable at the origin?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I need to check whether following function is differentiable at (0,0)
$$
F(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
\exp\left(-\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}\right) & \text{if } (x,y) \neq (0,0) \\
0 & \text{if } (x,y) = (0,0)
\end{cases}
$$
My attempt:

I checked that it is continuous at origin. Also to check differentiability I checked if $$\lim \frac{f (0+h,0+k)-f (0,0)-dz}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}=0$$ hence differentiable.

Comment: The differential at $(0,0)$ is also $0$ (a $0$ linear functional, or if you want, a vector). I assume you also checked $\frac{ f(h,k)}{\sqrt{h^2 + k^2}} \to 0$.

Comment: Ya I checked its 0

Comment: What is the $dz$ in your last limit?

Comment: dz comes to be zero

Answer (score 3):

The function
$$f(t):=\left\{\eqalign{e^{-1/t}\quad&(t>0) \cr 0\quad&(t\leq0)\cr}\right.$$
is differentiable on all of ${\Bbb R}$ since
$$\lim_{t\to0+}{e^{-1/t}-0\over t}=\lim_{\tau\to\infty}\tau\>e^{-\tau}=0\ .$$
The function $$g:\quad{\mathbb R}^2\to{\mathbb R},\qquad  (x,y)\mapsto x^2+y^2$$ is differentiable; therefore  the composition $F=f\circ g$ is differentiable on all of ${\Bbb R}^2$ as well.